# How does Gnome make the link between my music folder and the folder-music icon?

Tags: gnome, theme, icons

My music folder has a different icon from the other folders.
Gnome use the folder-music icon to personalize the music folder icon.

I would like to know where (in which configuration file or where in GConf, DConf) this association is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults (global) and ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs (local) contain the directions to default directories. The [xdg-user-dirs-update command](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/1/xdg-user-dirs-update/) may also be of some use to you.

Edit: Sorry, I should have been far more specific. In gnome, the file manager Nautilus constantly monitors the XDG configuration files for changes, and is hard-coded throughout (for example; [nautilus-icon-names.h](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=hnAU1Eotf90aHcUnNLHeRS_h6IU&cid=cbGpRLcV6jw&s=&browser=Default#L0)) to match the specific pixmap to the specified XDG folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is how Gnome makes the link between a folder and its icon. Not where is the default folder configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, this is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the xdg-user-dirs package and logging in anew made this work for me ...

The tracker apps seem look to the xdg cfg for where to mine.